# overlapping times to first available swimlane

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to set up a dataset for a report that requires certain tasks to be displayed in so called swimlanes, i.e. when 2 times overlap, they're displayed on 2 different rows in the report and does not overlap visually (on the same row).

I've come so far that I have the basics sorted, but it can get complicated with numerous times overlapping in chains where the end of the chain doesn't overlap the beginning.

Furthermore, the data is separated different categories. I felt it only necessary to include one (channel) to display that functionality.

This is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    StartTime   DATETIME
    ,Duration   INT
    ,Id         INT
    ,Channel    INT
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:30:32', 1827, 261832091, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:34:53', 1686, 265169258, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:44:16', 403, 136756869, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:50:45', 2112, 493664900, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:54:44', 1459, 356826302, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:55:01', 2620, 441592787, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 01:05:32', 546, 62903133, 3)

SELECT Swimlane
,StartTime
,EndTime
,Id
,Channel

FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN tt.id = tt2.id THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt.id, tt2.Channel ORDER BY tt.StartTime, tt2.StartTime, tt2.Channel) ELSE NULL END AS 'Swimlane'
    ,tt.StartTime
    ,DATEADD(SECOND, tt.Duration, tt.StartTime) AS 'EndTime'
    ,tt.Id
    ,tt.Channel
    ,tt2.StartTime AS 'StartTime2'
    ,DATEADD(SECOND, tt2.Duration, tt2.StartTime) AS 'EndTime2'
    ,tt2.Id AS 'Id2'
    ,tt2.Channel AS 'Channel2'

    FROM @TempTable tt
    LEFT JOIN @TempTable tt2 ON tt.StartTime >= tt2.StartTime
        AND DATEADD(SECOND, tt.Duration, tt.StartTime) >= tt2.StartTime
        AND DATEADD(SECOND, tt2.Duration, tt2.StartTime) >= tt.StartTime
        AND tt.Channel = tt2.Channel
) a

WHERE a.Swimlane IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY StartTime
```

This gives the result:

```
Swimlane StartTime             EndTime               Id          Channel
1        2017-10-05 00:30:32   2017-10-05 01:00:59   261832091   2
1        2017-10-05 00:34:53   2017-10-05 01:02:59   265169258   3
2        2017-10-05 00:44:16   2017-10-05 00:50:59   136756869   3
2        2017-10-05 00:50:45   2017-10-05 01:25:57   493664900   2
3        2017-10-05 00:54:44   2017-10-05 01:19:03   356826302   2
2        2017-10-05 00:55:01   2017-10-05 01:38:41   441592787   3
2        2017-10-05 01:05:32   2017-10-05 01:14:38   62903133    3
```

It works perfectly up to where the last row here ends up in the same row as the previous one, as it only overlaps the previous one, but not the one before it.
Preferably the last row should end up on swimlane 1 as it's empty, but if I get it down to swimlane 3, I'm happy with that as well.

I'm hoping this makes sense. It makes sense to me, but I've been stuck in this for quite some time so I might be glaring over something that I should explain.

All the data here are of course just randomised noise basically, but I believe this data shows my problem sufficiently.

Comment: So you want to assign a Swimlane for each row without overlapping.

Comment: Basically, yes. It should be within it's own category (in this case only Channel), and preferably the first available swimlane.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Swimlane to your temp table and initialize it to 1. You could then increase it as long as conflicts are found. You can convert 4 into null if only 3 lanes are available.

**Partial solution**

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    StartTime   DATETIME
    ,Duration   INT
    ,Id         INT
    ,Channel    INT
    ,Swimlane   tinyint default 1
    ,EndTime    as  DATEADD(SECOND, Duration, StartTime)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:30:32', 1827, 261832091, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:34:53', 1686, 265169258, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:44:16', 403, 136756869, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:50:45', 2112, 493664900, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:54:44', 1459, 356826302, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 00:55:01', 2620, 441592787, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(StartTime, Duration, Id, Channel)
VALUES('2017-10-05 01:05:32', 546, 62903133, 3)


while 1=1 begin
    update  conflict
    set Swimlane    =   nullif(conflict.Swimlane+1,4)
    FROM            @TempTable  as  booking
        inner join  @TempTable  as  conflict
            on  conflict.Id         >   booking.Id
            and conflict.Channel    =   booking.Channel
            and conflict.Swimlane   =   booking.Swimlane
            and (   conflict.StartTime  between booking.StartTime and booking.EndTime
                or  conflict.EndTime    between booking.StartTime and booking.EndTime
                or  booking.StartTime   between conflict.StartTime and conflict.EndTime
                or  booking.EndTime     between conflict.StartTime and conflict.EndTime
            )
    ;

    if @@ROWCOUNT <= 0 break;
end


SELECT 
    Swimlane
,   StartTime
,   EndTime
,   Id
,   Channel
from    @TempTable
ORDER BY    StartTime
;
```

**Known issue**

In case of a conflict the greater id is always moved. In the example below we should put ids 2&4 on lane 2, instead of ids 2&3 (current solution).

```
==============  id:1  time:1-5  lane:1     correct:1
=======         id:2  time:1-3  lane:2     correct:2
       =======  id:4  time:3-5  lane:3     correct:2
=====           id:5  time:1-2  lane:3     correct:3
         =====  id:3  time:4-5  lane:2     correct:3
     ====       id:6  time:2-4  lane:null  correct:3
```

It should work better if we populate the lanes with the earliest possible non-conflicting bookings instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's little bit over my head but I think I understand the basics of it anyway.
Just one thing though. There's necessarily no correlation between the id's being higher or lower between 2 tasks though, so I removed that criteria. It shouldn't change much, should it?
I'm still trying to adapt this to the live data so I don't know right now, but this seems to be what I needed. Very much appreciated.

Comment: `conflict.Id         >   booking.Id` is in the join conditions cause we only want to move one of the conflicting bookings. If you remove the condition, both conflicting records will be moved (and conflict on another lane).